# Extracting or computing "Component Score Coefficient Matrix" from PCA in SPSS using R

Tags: r, pca

I am using example data "mtcars" to compute a PCA in R:

```
pca <- principal(mtcars, nfactors = 2, rotate = "varimax")
```

There is no deeper meaning behind the specification, just an example with two factors. However, now I want to extract a so called "Component Score Coefficient Matrix" (terminology from SPSS). See also the following link:
https://docs.displayr.com/wiki/Component_Score_Coefficient_Matrix

Using SPSS, i am able to extract this "Component Score Coefficient Matrix" after computing PCA with 2 factors and varimax rotation:

[image]

Based on the SPSS documentation, these are the coefficients by which the variables are multiplied to obtain factor scores. Is there any way to extract this kind of coefficients(-matrix) with the function "principal"? Or any other function to compute pca in R? A calculation by hand would also be helpful. I am grateful for any help.

Comment: try `pca$weights`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) provided the right answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281572/extracting-or-computing-component-score-coefficient-matrix-from-pca-in-spss-us/73282397#comment129419076_73281572):

> try `pca$weights`